# Como criar o chão do jogo com um prefab aleatório

Tags: unity3d

Para criar o chão, fiz da seguinte maneira:

Criei um gameobject e depois atribuí um sprite render, box colider, rigidbody 2d e um script.

Criei um prefab e arrastei o gameobject que defini acima para cima do prefab e pronto, assim criei o meu chão e o prefab que será adicionado ao jogo a medida que o jogador avança.

Criei também 2 outros objectos, um para adicionar um novo prefab (que é o meu chão) e outro para destrui-lo quando sair do limite da câmera a medida que o jogador avança.

No script que atribui ao prefab verifico se há alguma colisão com um dos 2 objectos acima e removo ou adiciono um novo prefab:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o)
    if (o.tag == "CreateGround"){
        Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Ground"), new Vector3 (5.4f, -4.574f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    else if (o.tag == "DestroyGround")
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente para um tipo de chão, porém tenho outros 3 tipos de chão/prefab com polygon collider no lugar do box collider (por ter uma forma diferente).

Como faço para que o novo chão a ser adicionado seja um random dos 4 prefabs que tenho?

Para entender melhor o que eu escrevi acima, veja a imagem (qualquer semelhança com o super mario é apenas copydência):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posso dar uma sugestão? Crie uma classe que vai administrar teu 'Mapa'
Senão pule para a parte dois.

**1 - Classe Mapa**

adicione dois componentes, vamos usar eles para sortear um número aleatório e montar uma lista.

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random //Para sortear um número aleatório
using System.Colections.Generic //opcional para listas.
```

Dentro da classe coloque pelo menos uma variável, neste caso
`chaoTipos` é uma lista que conterá todos os teus tipos de chão.
Você também pode usar uma lista para powerups, inimigos e por ai vai.

```
public GameObject[] chaoTipos; //se quiser uma aleatoriedade maior crie uma variavel para cada componente que forma o chão e você pode combinar eles ex:powerups, armadilhas, inimigos --- essa lista você pode arrastar direto no Inspector.
```

Depois uma variável para pendurar teu chão, assim ficará tudo organizadinho na hierarchy.

```
public Transform cenario; //vamos pendurar todos os pedacos aqui
public List <Vector3> posições = new List<Vector3> //lista das possíveis posições do cenário. Vai ser util se o mapa mudar a cada fase
```

**Método**

Cada vez que for criar um componente novo, recomendo pegar o X,Y da nova posição, se você tiver usado a lista de posições, pode pegar dela.

Você pode fazer, é identico ao teu código, a diferença é que eu penduro tudo que é criado num componente pai para ter mais controle sobre ele:

```
GameObject paraInstanciar = chaoTipos[Random.range(0,chaoTipos.Length] //pega um dos tipos de chão que você tem
GameObject instancia = Intantiate(paraInstanciar, new Vector3(X,Y,0f),      Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; //Instancia um deles
instancia.transform.setParent(cenario); //se seguir a parte um, para pendurar tudo relativo ao tabuleiro
```

E para remover bastaria tirar ele do pai.

**2 direto no código (ou, só atualizando o que você mandou na pergunta)**

Antes de chamar o método (assim como o que explico na parte 1)

```
public GameObject[] chaoTipos //pendure todos os tipos aqui
```

Dentro do trigger que você usa.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o)
if (o.tag == "CreateGround"){
    GameObject paraInstanciar = chaoTipos[Random.range(0,chaoTipos.Length)];
    Instantiate(paraInstanciar , new Vector3 (5.4f, -4.574f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
else if (o.tag == "DestroyGround")
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

> Fonte https://youtu.be/B_nXuYgfLh8 - é um mapa criado proceduralmente antes do jogo começar mas o principio é o mesmo.

-- *desculpe se houver algum erro no código, fiz direto no editor do stackoverflow*

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54225/discussion-on-answer-by-nils-como-criar-o-chao-do-jogo-com-um-prefab-aleatorio)